# Use of xp_cmdshell in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to execute a perl script from `xp_cmdshell`.

The output of the perl script is a csv file, but when I run

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell N'perl G:\script\perl.pl';
```

I can't find the csv file created, though the `xp_cmdshell` command seems to run fine, the output is the name of file that has to be created.

I am using `xp_cmdshell` to create a job step to execute the perl script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running this via a SQL Agent job, it'll be much safer to disable the use of xp_cmdshell via sp_configure ([ref1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx) | [ref2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631.aspx)) and use a [CmdExec job step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264.aspx) instead.

When configuring the job step, be sure to go to the advanced page and enable job step logging to a table.

[image: Verbose Logging]

This will allow you to better troubleshoot the issues you're having with the perl job in general, as the issue could be related to something entirely outside the context of the database engine.

Comment: tnx for the reply , but I can't figure out where the file has been saved. `Job 'test' : Step 1, 'esecuzione' : Began Executing 2016-05-03 15:59:41  
output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
03_05_2016_155942_output.csv  
(null)  

(2 rows(s) affected)`

Comment: What does the job output show?  Go back into the job, edit the step, go to the advanced page and then click the "View" button.  This should show the step output.  If it's not shown there, you likely need to edit your perl script in case it's creating the output at a static path.

Comment: The job output shows what I wrote in the previous comment. By the way I solved, as you suggested, adding to perl script a static path. Many tnx @john